# pcsc-sharp Mifare Authentication

Tags: nfc, smartcard, mifare, apdu, contactless-smartcard

I'm using the [pcsc-sharp](https://github.com/danm-de/pcsc-sharp) library to communicate with an ACR122U Reader an read/write information to MIFARE Classic 1k cards.

After getting familiar with the library and the APDU concept I'm able to use the cards UID as identifier in my applications. 
Now I am in need of setting my own ID's to the card. Therefore I read some manuals regarding NXP's MIFARE (like [MF1S70YYX_V1](https://web.archive.org/web/20161101201335/http://cache.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/MF1S70YYX_V1.pdf?pspll=1)) and also got some information about [ISO 7816-4](http://www.cardwerk.com/smartcards/smartcard_standard_ISO7816-4_6_basic_interindustry_commands.aspx).

I'm aware of the need to do authentication before accessing the cards memory to perform read/write operations and I know the standard Key value.

I downloaded the pcsc-sharp examples from GitHub and ran the Mifare1kTest example. I works but `card.LoadKey` in Line 36 fails. The response values of the Apdu command in `LoadKey` is SW1=99 SW2=0, which I cannot find in any documentation. Commenting out the "throw new Exception" section makes the example work.

My question now is, which values are the correct ones to pass to `Card.LoadKey`, respectively which are the correct values to use for parameters in the Apdu Command. What is meant with "keynumber" (Sectornumber - Sector/Block Combination)? Is the `LoadKey` call necessary, if the example works?

Comment: Usually anything in the 9xxx range means success, with the xxx being additional information. If I remember correctly the APDU wrap will put the MiFare response within the status word (but hey, I've programmed the interface in one day, some year ago, my mind isn't that young anymore). Have you tried if the key load was successful by using the key?

Comment: The key has to be loaded in the **volatile** part of the readers memory. The example Hands over 'KeyStructure,NonVolalatileMemory'. Doing so as described **Mr Heart** in answer below the example works. The results for SW1 / SW2 are 90 00.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is broad, but these should work for you. Code is explained with comments

```
var loadKeySuccessful = card.LoadKey(
    KeyStructure.VolatileMemory,
    0x00, // first key slot
    new byte[] {0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF} // key
);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. You are right. loading the key into **volatile memory** solved the problem. It is also described in the ACR122U Application Programming Manual but somehow I missed it.

Comment: @MatthiasFuchs if that's the right answer mark it as correct so as to help other people searching for solutions.